# What's the simplest way to parse an XML string in Node.js?

Tags: xml, node.js

I'm looking around and not seeing an obvious way to parse XML in Node.  I'm assuming that there's some relatively straight forward XML object that I can pass a String or url to, but I'm not finding anything like that in the spec. Do I need an external lib? and if so, which one would you guys recommend? I don't need xPath (though I wouldn't mind it) as long as I can walk the tree in an obvious way (test if nodeType == ElementNode and loop through children).

Comment: Off topic for opinion-seeking "what's the simplest?" and asking for recommendations ("which one would you guys recommend?").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of XML modules listed [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml) where perhaps you may find one that works best for you. A popular one that I'm aware of is [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js). There are also [libxml bindings](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) if you're already familiar with that library.

Comment: first link is dead.

Answer (score 14):

I suggest [xml2js](https://npmjs.org/package/xml2js), a simple XML to JavaScript object converter. You can then iterate the resulting object. Code snippet from the page :

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

You can install it by using `npm install xml2js`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Express along with body parser, the simplest way would be to use [express-xml-bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-xml-bodyparser). It allows to parse XML for all routes or specific ones, depending on your scenario

All routes:

```
const xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
// .. other middleware ... 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(xmlparser());
// ... other middleware ... 

app.post('/receive-xml', function(req, res, next) {

  // req.body contains parsed XML as JSON

});
```

Specific routes:

```
app.post('/receive-xml', xmlparser({trim: false, explicitArray: false}), function(req, res, next) {
  // req.body contains parsed XML as JSON  
});
```

Answer (score -4):

If it isn't an absolute requirement that it has to be done server side, then on the client you could use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) to parse into string, and [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) to parse into DOM.

XMLSerializer Example (from DOM to string):

```
var XMLS = new XMLSerializer();
var elem = document;
var xml_str = XMLS.serializeToString(elem);
console.log(xml_str);
```

DOMParser Example (from string to DOM):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml_str, "application/xml");
console.log(doc);
```

Comment: I don't have a "client side" in my environment. This is actually to parse a response that comes back to a cron process from a third party provider in the form of XML. But thanks. :)

Comment: this shouldn't have been downvoted given the original question. Works pretty well.

Comment: This question is specific to nodejs so I will just let anyone else that comes across this that node does not have a DomParser it's a browser thing.